# Users created in Kickstart unable to authenticate

Tags: centos, authentication, password, kickstart, rhel8

Thanks to the answers to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/588532/anaconda-kickstart-and-rootpw-option), I've been happily generating Kickstart files for Scientific Linux 6 and 7 for the past 5 years. However, we're now starting to build out some test systems with CentOS 8 and running into some issues.

Despite using the same method for generating hashes (or indeed, reusing the very same hashes) the passwords for the users are not being set correctly. I've been unable to find any documentation suggesting there's been a change between EL 7 and 8.

Here's a test user I'm creating in the Kickstart file:

```
user --homedir=/var/ftp --name=A3857275828 --password=$6$J52QJaSjIt8GGqRS$4YyusOJ5EtpikCdwgXJrorW7XyiLRCT.jjRZsHLv04ZV7ng8wTdrwFUF2u5QXGWiEmDgu/g9RpXxLKPoRD4Kh0 --iscrypted --shell=/usr/sbin/nologin --uid=5001 --gid=5001
```

The password should be `9282759601013452` but logins are failing until I manually change the password using the `passwd` utility. I'm seeing the same failures on **all** non-privileged accounts created but **the root password works fine.** Password-based logins have been tested using both SSH and FTP (vsftpd backed by PAM.)

`/var/log/anaconda/journal.log` shows nothing interesting during the setup process:

```
Jun 26 20:52:17 test.test.local anaconda[1946]: program: Running... useradd -R /mnt/sysimage -g 5001 -d /var/ftp -M -s /usr/sbin/nologin -u 5001 A3857275828
Jun 26 20:52:17 test.test.local useradd[35591]: new user: name=A3857275828, UID=5001, GID=5001, home=/var/ftp, shell=/usr/sbin/nologin
```

The entry in `/etc/shadow` has the same hash specified in the Kickstart file:

```
A3857275828:$6$J52QJaSjIt8GGqRS$4YyusOJ5EtpikCdwgXJrorW7XyiLRCT.jjRZsHLv04ZV7ng8wTdrwFUF2u5QXGWiEmDgu/g9RpXxLKPoRD4Kh0::0:99999:7:::
```

And after updating with `passwd`, it's still a valid SHA-512 hash:

```
A3857275828:$6$SP6IoLdZemXHZbxp$E3/Owe7mciCkeuHdiX4ZnZDUWmTz3nDqa885Rnc3rHMZcPharyX0QSdsUTq3gMneSNsmD1V.FmRf5HCY.uZqH0:18452:0:99999:7:::
```

The only other file that's touched during a password update is `/var/lib/sss/mc/passwd`. However, I'm not using `authselect` in my Kickstart file and `authselect current` says "No existing configuration detected." From what I've read, this should mean that sssd is out of the picture (anyway, as far as I can see, it's only used for external authentication.)

PAM config is untouched from the default, and I've added the `debug` option to `pam_unix.so` but am not getting much verbosity out of it:

```
Jul 10 17:00:06 pbxtest login[972]: pam_unix(login:auth): username [admin] obtained
Jul 10 17:00:08 pbxtest login[972]: pam_unix(login:auth): authentication failure; logname=LOGIN uid=0 euid=0 tty=tty1 ruser= rhost=  user=admin
Jul 10 17:00:10 pbxtest login[972]: FAILED LOGIN 1 FROM tty1 FOR admin, Authentication failure
```

In the event I'm misunderstanding SSSD, here is `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
passwd:      sss files systemd
shadow:     files sss
group:       sss files systemd
hosts:      files dns myhostname
services:   files sss
netgroup:   sss
automount:  files sss
aliases:    files
ethers:     files
gshadow:    files
networks:   files dns
protocols:  files
publickey:  files
rpc:        files
```

(Which, now that I look at it, seems like sssd *is* getting in the way of things.) There are no files under `/etc/sssd/` and the status looks like this:

```
● sssd.service - System Security Services Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sssd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-10-22 17:16:49 EDT; 6 days ago
 Main PID: 899 (sssd)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4428)
   Memory: 6.4M
   CGroup: /system.slice/sssd.service
           ├─899 /usr/sbin/sssd -i --logger=files
           ├─940 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_be --domain implicit_files --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
           └─944 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_nss --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
```

Any thoughts on why I'm unable to log in with the expected password until setting it with `passwd`?

Comment: Congrats, you have a proper mystery on your hands! I have no idea what's going on there.

Comment: I would check permissions on `passwd` and `shadow` files and selinux context (if it is enforcing, just do `restorecon -rv /etc`). Maybe kickstart is messing them up.

Comment: @Tomek selinux is disabled

Comment: I validated the Kickstart hash - it's intact and that is the plain that cracks it with hashcat. The only other thing that I see that's different is field 3 of the shadow field ("date of last password change"). Is there anything on the system that enforces password rotation / age?

Comment: @RoyceWilliams no password policies in place, and this is a fresh install anyway, so that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Sounds like SSSD to me. Can you show your /etc/nsswitch.conf together with /etc/sssd/sssd.conf plus systemctl status sssd? You also have /usr/sbin/nologin shell set so users won't be able to log in (although they should be able to authenticate). [Local users are cached by SSSD](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/considerations_in_adopting_rhel_8/identity-management_considerations-in-adopting-rhel-8#local-users-cached-by-sssd-nsssss_considerations-in-adopting-RHEL-8)